# Setting label text on a UIViewController from a Non-UIViewController Class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a `UIViewController` and I'm refactoring it and I've bumped into a situation where I need to update it from another class. I know I need to use the [delegate pattern](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/), but I'm having a tough time finding an example that fits my situation (which I think it dirt simple).

`ItemViewController` has a `Timer` class that's instantiated. I'm trying to update an `ItemViewController` label from the `Timer` class.

On `Timer`, I've done the following:

```
weak var delegate: TimerDelegate? // weak to avoid a retain cycle

func updateLabel(timeRemaining: Int) -> String {
    return formatTimeInSeconds(timeRemaining) // another method w/in Timer
}
```

I declare the `protocol` at the bottom of the `Timer` class

```
protocol TimerDelegate: class {
    func updateLabel(timeString: String) -> String
}
```

On `ItemViewController` I have the following property declared:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timeValueLabel: UILabel?
```

I set it as a delegate of `Timer` in `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
timer.delegate = self
```

What I'm trying to make happen is when `updateLabel` is called on `Timer`, I'd like to update `timeValueLabel.text` on `ItemViewController`. This is where I'm stuck...what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Timer` class assign from any where and you need to change the text of label you can use singleton object for that, create one singleton object with your `Timer` class then use that object to set delegate like this way.

```
class Timer {
    static let sharedInstance = Timer()
    weak var delegate: TimerDelegate?

    //Now use this delegate to call method.
    func updateLabel(timeRemaining: Int) -> String {
        delegate?.updateLabel(formatTimeInSeconds(timeRemaining) 
        return formatTimeInSeconds(timeRemaining) 
    }         
}
```

Now you need to just set this delegate in your `ItemViewController` like this.

```
class ItemViewController: UIViewController, TimerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Timer.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    }

    func updateLabel(timeString: String) -> String
        self.label.text = timeString
        return "" //return string that you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That got me over the finish line :)

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do:

```
func updateLabel(timeRemaining: Int) -> String {
    let formattedTime = formatTimeInSeconds(timeRemaining)
    delegate.updateLabel(formattedTime)
    return formattedTime
}
```

And in the ItemViewController you should declare that the class follows the delegate and implement the declared method. Something like:

```
class ItemViewController: TimerDelegate {
    ...
    func updateLabel(timeString: String) -> String {
        ...
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you for looking. What goes inside `class ItemViewController: TimerDelegate`'s method?